# Swift, core data, add item from modally presented view

Tags: swift, core-data

I am updating an app into Swift and have a tableView to which items can be added from a modally presented view. This works fine when the Save button is pressed, but when cancel is pressed the table view is presented with a blank line at the top, showing that an empty item was added. What am I missing?

The AddViewController protocol is:

```
protocol NewGaugeDelegate {

func didFinish(viewController:AddGaugeViewController, didSave:Bool)
```

}

and the didSave function is:

```
extension AddGaugeViewController {

@IBAction func cancelButtonWasTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    delegate?.didFinish(viewController: self, didSave: false)
}

@IBAction func saveButtonWasTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    addGauge()
    delegate?.didFinish(viewController: self, didSave: true)
}
```

}

in the tableView controller, the protocol is accessed like this:

```
extension GaugeTableViewController: NewGaugeDelegate {

func didFinish(viewController: AddGaugeViewController, didSave: Bool) {
    guard didSave,
        let context = viewController.context,
        context.hasChanges else {
            dismiss(animated: true)
            return
    }

    context.perform {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            fatalError("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        self.coreDataStack.saveContext()
    }

    dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

}

Suggestions as to why the cancel function is not working properly would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess when you present the modal view you are inserting entity in the context and after that u are not removing it ? On save you are saving context but when do you remove the entry that was added in the context ?

Comment: Good point, I will look at that.